# SQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   
            @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
            @startdate datetime =  '2017-04-01',  
            @enddate datetime  =  '2017-04-30'

SET @query = '
select *  from Tb_T_Article  where Created_Date < convert(date,' +@enddate+ ',105)
'
print @query
   EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: If you look at sql in @query, then you'll notice that the date value isn't quoted.  And you can add a single qoute by adding 2 : `''`

Answer (score 0):

Hey please try the below code, and see if that works

```
DECLARE @enddate datetime
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @enddate = '02-02-2012 6:10:00:000'

SET @query = 'SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@enddate,105)'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query,N'@enddate date',@enddate
```